# Unity webplayer cache - deleting files manually

Tags: caching, unity-game-engine

I know there is a scripting API for deleting the unity player cache...e.g. `Caching.CleanCache ()` - but I need to clean the player cache out of the scope of my game, my launcher app needs the ability to purge these contents...

I noticed the drop spot for the cache is `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\Cache`

Is it safe to just delete the contents in my project's directory to achieve this goal?

Also - I am only concerned with windows users.

Thanks

Comment: so, what happens if you delete it? its not like your computer is going to explode if it doesnt give you the desired result (which is unlikely anyway). ofc for the imo low chance something goes sideways pretty bad -> backup, backup, backup ;)